# How to obtain the scale and rotation angle from LogPolar transform

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm trying to use LogPolar transform to obtain the scale and the rotation angle from two images. Below are two 300x300 sample images. The first rectangle is 100x100, and the second rectangle is 150x150, rotated by 45 degree.

[image]
[image]

The algorithm:

1. Convert both images to LogPolar.
2. Find the translational shift using Phase Correlation.
3. Convert the translational shift to scale and rotation angle (how to do this?).

My code:

```
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc_c.h>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    cv::Mat a = cv::imread("rect1.png", 0);
    cv::Mat b = cv::imread("rect2.png", 0);
    if (a.empty() || b.empty())
        return -1;

    cv::imshow("a", a);
    cv::imshow("b", b);

    cv::Mat pa = cv::Mat::zeros(a.size(), CV_8UC1);
    cv::Mat pb = cv::Mat::zeros(b.size(), CV_8UC1);
    IplImage ipl_a = a, ipl_pa = pa;
    IplImage ipl_b = b, ipl_pb = pb;
    cvLogPolar(&ipl_a, &ipl_pa, cvPoint2D32f(a.cols >> 1, a.rows >> 1), 40);
    cvLogPolar(&ipl_b, &ipl_pb, cvPoint2D32f(b.cols >> 1, b.rows >> 1), 40);

    cv::imshow("logpolar a", pa);
    cv::imshow("logpolar b", pb);

    cv::Mat pa_64f, pb_64f;
    pa.convertTo(pa_64f, CV_64F);
    pb.convertTo(pb_64f, CV_64F);

    cv::Point2d pt = cv::phaseCorrelate(pa_64f, pb_64f);

    std::cout << "Shift = " << pt 
              << "Rotation = " << cv::format("%.2f", pt.y*180/(a.cols >> 1)) 
              << std::endl;

    cv::waitKey(0);

    return 0;
}
```

The log polar images:

[image]
[image]

For the sample image images above, the translational shift is `(16.2986, 36.9105)`. I have successfully obtain the rotation angle, which is `44.29`. But I have difficulty in calculating the scale. How to convert the given translational shift to obtain the scale?

Comment: HI, Can you go through the paper" ROBUST IMAGE REGISTRATION USING LOG-POLAR TRANSFORM by George Wolberg"... i Think it is very simple and clear on how to recover scale and rotation in Log-Polar Space....

Comment: @G453 I've read the paper and also some others. I don't know if the explanations in the papers are unclear or its me that so stupid but I still cannot write the proper code for recovering the scale.

Comment: The shift vector has 2 coordinates, one is the angle and the other is the log of the scale.

Comment: @n.m. yes I know that. What I'm looking for is the *formula* to recover the scale given the shift vector, source image width and height, logpolar width and height, etc.

Comment: Given the shift vector (rho,theta) the angle is theta and the scale is exp(rho). No other data is relevant.

Comment: @bsdnoobz did you ever get the answer to this?

Comment: Hi, Can you tell the scaling ratio that you used to generate 1st and 2nd image. I got the scale value 1.17 for the images.

Answer (score 2):

You have two Images *f1*, *f2* with *f1(m, n) = f2(m/a , n/a)* That is *f1* is scaled by factor a

In logarithmic notation that is equivalent to *f1(log m, log n) = f2(logm − log a, log n − log a)* where *log a* is the shift in your phasecorrelated image.

Compare *B. S. Reddy, B. N. Chatterji: An FFT-Based Technique for Translation, Rotation and
Scale-Invariant Image Registration, IEEE Transactions On Image Processing Vol. 5
No. 8, IEEE, 1996*

http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.185.4387&rep=rep1&type=pdf

Comment: The expected scaling factor is 1.5 and the translational shift in x-axis is 16.2986. If `log a = 16.2986`, then `a = 10 ^ 16.2986`?

Comment: Make sure you consider the logarithmic conversion described in C, page 2 of the linked IEEE document.

Comment: By the way, in your code you calculate the translational shift as well. You have to do that in a second step using the angle and scale corrected image as input.

Answer (score 2):

[here is python version](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/code/imreg.py.html)

which tells

```
ir = abs(ifft2((f0 * f1.conjugate()) / r0))
    i0, i1 = numpy.unravel_index(numpy.argmax(ir), ir.shape)
    angle = 180.0 * i0 / ir.shape[0]
    scale = log_base ** i1
```

Answer (score 1):

The value for the scale factor is indeed `exp(pt.y)`. However, since you used a "magnitude scale parameter" of 40 for the **cvLogPolar** function, you now need to divide pt.x by 40 to get the correct value for the displacement:

```
Scale = exp( pt.x / 40) = exp(16.2986 / 40) = 1.503
```

The value of the "magnitude scale parameter" for the **cvLogPolar** function does not affect the displacement produced by the rotation angle pt.x, because according to the math, it cancels out. For that reason, your formula for the rotation gives the correct value.

On another note, I believe the formula for the rotation should actually be:

Rotation = pt.y*360/(a.cols)

But, for some strange reason, the ">> 1" that you added is causing the result to be multiplied by 2 (which I believe you compensated for by multiplying by 180 instead of 360?) Remove it, and you'll see what I mean.

Also, ">>1" is causing a division by 2 in:

cvPoint2D32f(a.cols >> 1, a.rows >> 1)

If to set the center parameter of the cvLogPolar function to the center of the image (which is what you want):

cvPoint2D32f(a.cols/2, a.rows/2)

and

cvPoint2D32f(b.cols/2, b.rows/2)

then, you'll also get the correct value for the rotation (i.e. the same value that you got), and for the scale.

Answer (score 1):

This thread was helpful in getting me started on rotation-invariant phase correlation, so I hope my input will help resolve any lingering issues.

We aim to calculate the scale and rotation (which is incorrectly calculated in the code). Let's start by gathering the equations from the [logPolar docs](http://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/da/d54/group__imgproc__transform.html#gaec3a0b126a85b5ca2c667b16e0ae022d). There they state the following:

```
(1) I = (dx,dy) = (x-center.x, y-center.y)
(2) rho = M * ln(magnitude(I))
(3) phi = Ky * angle(I)_0..360
```

*Note: rho is pt.x and phi is pt.y in the code above*

We also know that

```
(4) M = src.cols/ln(maxRadius)
(5) Ky = src.rows/360
```

First, let's solve for scale. Solving for magnitude(I) (i.e. scale) in equation 2, we get

```
(6) magnitude(I) = scale = exp(rho/M)
```

Then we substitute for M and simplify to get

```
(7) magnitude(I) = scale = exp(rho*ln(maxRadius)/src.cols) = pow(maxRadius, rho/src.cols)
```

Now let's solve for rotation. Solving for angle(I) (i.e. rotation) in equation 3, we get

```
(8) angle(I) = rotation = phi/Ky
```

Then we substitute for Ky and simplify to get

```
(9) angle(I) = rotation = phi*360/src.rows
```

So, scale and rotation can be calculated using equations 7 and 9, respectively. It might be worth noting that you should use equation 4 for calculation M and `Point2f center( (float)a.cols/2, (float)a.rows/2 )` for calculating center as opposed to what is in the code above. There are good bits of info in this [logpolar example opencv code](http://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/dc/d5e/polar_transforms_8cpp-example.html#a12).

Answer (score 0):

From the values by phase correlation, the coordinates are rectangular coordinates hence   (16.2986, 36.9105) are (x,y). The scale is calculated as

scale = log((x^2 + y^ 2)^0.5) which is approximately 1.6(near to 1.5).

When we calculate angle by using formulae theta = arctan(y/x) = 66(approx).
The theta value is way of the real value(45 in this case).