# Comparison of one image with a base of images

Tags: python, opencv, surf, matcher, flann

I want to compare an image of a front of a car with a database of images with other cars and tell me that most likely match of it.

Program firstly shall find key points and descriptors of the database of the images using SURF and try to compare them with `Flann matcher`.

But I simply can't understand how it should work. I'll have matches of the various pairs of images, but how can I compare the images and show relative output?

Comment: I suggest to show us a database of test images in the first place

Comment: Find Good matches in from them, and compare the no. of good matches, the match with highest good matches will be the most likely image...check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20653044/matching-template-imgescaled-to-main-larger-image , that someone had given to me, you have to change many things in that but you comes to know about good matches and will get the idea of finding the best match

Comment: Ok - so instead of using flann I'll use knnmatcher (KNearest). And my thinking process is that after finding descriptors of database images I will put them together into one matrix as samples and my responses will be float numbers. After using matcher I'll will just check if result is 1 - it is bmw or 2 it is audi or 3 kia and so on 

Well is it good thinking ?