# Converting OpenCV code from iOS to Android

Tags: android, ios, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I want to convert the following openCV code(available in iOS) at [Matching template imge(scaled) to Main/larger image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20653044/matching-template-imgescaled-to-main-larger-image?noredirect=1#comment30921784_20653044) to Android.

I have tried lot of things, but the opencv library has problem that surf detection is not available in OpenCV's Android Library. For using that they have told to use c++ code and doing some settings. Different sites are saying different settings. As i am totally new to android, i am not getting properly how to set it up. Please can anyone give me reliable and detailed way of doing that. or does anyone know ther other method of doing the same thing that is given in above question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found solution to my question, You can check it out the solution on this post:[Object detection with OpenCV Feature Matching with a threshold/similarity score - Java/C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17898480/object-detection-with-opencv-feature-matching-with-a-threshold-similarity-score/20994113#20994113)